# Is possible to share programs between Windows 8 on a VHD and Windows 7 on a physical disk?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot, vhd

I have a lot of programs installed on Windows 7 that I need on my Windows 8 (runs on a VHD). Do I need to duplicate all these installations or is there some tool that can update the Windows 8 system so that the programs on Windows 7 are accessible from it?

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible as most programs write details to the registry (assuming it has to be installed and isn't a stand alone program). However, if you could somehow duplicate these registry entries onto the OS then I have no idea!

Comment: Yes, the latter was what I was thinking too. A tool could hypothetically read all registry values of an installed program in Windows 7 and copy them to Windows 8. Perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Portable apps which does not have anything in registery.

- Share drive/folder between VHD and Local
- install portable apps there
- use both place

Only supported for portable apps